# Why doesn't Stack Exchange automatically display requested pages using given keywords, especially for typos?

Tags: feature-request, search

On this site today I was searching for something about cats on the [Pets Stack Exchange site](https://pets.stackexchange.com/). I made a spelling mistake of `forr cat` instead of `for cat`. It showed me

> *"No results found. Do you want to search for **for** cat instead?"*.

However, Google would have shown the intended pages rather than prodding me and would just mention -

> *"Showing results for **for** cat. Instead search for **forr** cat?"*.

Comment: You might have been asking about ***fur cat***, or ***furry***... In any case, the preposition "for" is so common in the English language, the results with "for" would be negligible, might as well just use the term "cats" alone.

Answer (score 6):

No, I don't like sites that **force** their opinions and suggestions on me.

Stack Exchange is consistent in this, and I like it:

- When viewing active questions list, it won't auto load questions with new activity but rather show a message and let you click before loading.
- When viewing a question and answer is edited/deleted it won't auto reload the page but rather show a banner and let you *choose* if you want to reload.
- ...and more.

I believe the above is the reason Stack Exchange is not behaving same way as Google.

Comment: The [‘french military victories’  meme](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/google-bombs/) could be mentioned.

Comment: @PeterMortensen lol... but on serious note, SE search isn't based on links so  can't be abused or bombed that way.